# TFS 2018 work item action

Tags: tfs

We modified the standard Scrum workflow and added a "Review and Test" state between "In Progress" and "Done". Now we would like to automatically transition from "In Progress" to "Review and Test" when a pull request is made for a work item. So far the only actions we see being used are Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.xxx where xxx may be StartWork, StopWork or Checkin.

Are there any more defined actions? Is some action with a pull request possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it through Pull Request Web Hooks with web app (e.g. web api), the simple workflow:

1. Create a Web Hooks with Pull request created event (it will send the request to target web app once creating the related Pull request)
2. Get necessary information from request in your web app (e.g. web api)
3. Get workitems of this pull request through [Pull Request REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/git/pull-requests/pull-requests#get-a-pull-request)

Comment: Thanks! I was hoping for a standard action flag but this could work.

Answer (score 0):

> **The first question is: what is Action?**
>
> It’s just **a unique string that used as a flag** that added in the
>   transition between states to be used by third party tools, so we can
>   know which is the current state and which is the next state for given
>   action in a work-item.

You could write any custom action just follow below limitations, Visual Studio ALM uses `Microsoft.VSTS.Actions.<your action>`.

- *Action names are programmatic names for which you can use only    English characters.*
- *Action names should follow the same reference namespace convention as    field reference names, to avoid action name conflicts between
  vendors    and customers. However, this convention is not enforced by
  the tool.*

For more details you could refer this blog: [Understanding Action for state transition in Details](http://mohamedradwan.com/2014/03/24/understanding-action-for-state-transation-in-details/)

You could also take a look at *Aliaksei Baturytski*'s reply in this [case](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4f40db2f-3440-4965-884d-dd915fdc03bc/work-item-action-list?forum=tfsworkitemtracking):

> Actions only provide hints to third party applications on what the
>   next state may be for a current state; they cannot be used to trigger
>   any custom actions during a transition.

---

For your requirement, you could achieve your objective,by using a serverside plugin that triggers after a workitem is changed. You could also use this 3-party extension [TFS Aggregator](https://tfsaggregator.github.io/) to handle it.

Comment: TFS Aggregator triggers after the workitem is changed. We need something that triggers the state transition of the work item itself when a pull request is made.